# Caching html from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, html, caching

Alright so I have no idea how to even begin doing this
But basically I have one of the menus that displays on every page come getting it's text and links from a mysql database.

Here's the code:

```
<table class="LeftMenuTable">
<?php
    // Generates the left menu from the LeftMenu_items table
    $result = MySqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Menu_LeftMenu;");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if ((int)$row['header'] == 0)
        {
            // echos value is on or not
            echo "<tr><td class='LeftMenu'><a href='" . $row['url'] . "'>" . $row['text'] . "</a></td></tr>";
        }
        else if ((int)$row['header'] == 1)
        {
            // header
            echo "<tr><td style='border:0px; height:5px;'></td></tr>";  // adds extra empty tabel
            echo "<tr><td class='LeftMenuHeader'><b><strong>" . $row['text'] . "</strong></b></td></tr>";
        }
    }
?>
</table>

function MySqlQuery($Query)
{

    $result = $mysqli->query($Query) or die(ReportMysqlError(mysqli_error($mysqli), $Query));
    return $result;
}
```

I feel like any sql queries that could be be replaced by html cache somehow are reducing the site's speed.

If anyone has any information or suggestions it's much appereciated.

Comment: It's interesting to know why you decided to use a database to store the static content? It supposed to be editable - if so, how often?

Comment: Id use a seperate file to store the menu HTML, then include it in the PHP script. Im not sure if HTML can include HTML from another page yet...

Comment: HTML cannot (we're not talking about frames, right? :) ), but SHTML files (server-side includes) are able to. )

Comment: Is speed really an issue or is this question just about premature optimization? As I see the question now it is just ok if it works. Why bother changing it to a caching solution? Generally there should be a very good reason to change existing working code. That might be speed or safety for example. But I don't think your code is in urgent need of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were keen enough, I would suggest a slightly different approach.

If you make your pages using a templating language called "Smarty" find out more here. http://smarty.net you should find that smarty will manage the caching for you.

How is this related to your question.

1. It will make your web development easier as you will stop "echoing" content into your HTML.
2. Smarty will do the caching for you. When a smarty template loads, smarty keeps a copy of it (or you can tell it cache a file for x hours, days etc).
3. As you site grows smartys caching will help keep your site running and loading fast.
4. You have to very little work to make caching work, just use smarty templates to build your site.
5. Lastly you may find it a LOT simpler to build sites using smarty.

John.

Answer (score 0):

In the method that calls your database (to fetch menu items and build the corresponding html):

1. Check if there is an item in the current `$_SESSION` with the html of your menu.
2. If (1) returns nothing, execute the query, build the html and store the results in `$_SESSION`.
3. Return the html of your menu.

A bit more information about how you can use the session can be found [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php).

This way, your menu query will only be fired `once` per session. I doubt it's a real performance breaker though (if your query is more or less in normal form).

Note that `changes` in your menu will not get picked up automatically before the session expires with the mechanism described above.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) (or some other similar solution) when I need to organize a caching layer.

But in your case may be it'd be done in a more simple way: use an intermediate 'generator' script which will be fired each time the table in question is updated (as it's updated from some form of admin panel, right?) and will generate a static file, then include this file within your main view script.